# After compiling QT 5 how do I to update my system? With update-alternatives?

Tags: compiling, qt, qt5

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.
I followed the instructions in [this guide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git) in order to compile QT5.
Everything compiled fine.

My problem now is that my QT related programs are still pointing to an older version of QT. For example, my `qmake` was pointing to an older 4.0 version rather than my new 5.0 version. To fix this, I did:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/qmake qmake /usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/bin/qmake 50
```

I noticed there are like 30 different programs inside the `/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/bin` folder. Is there a fast way to make sure all of these tools will be found or do I have to do a `sudo update-alternatives` for all of them one by one?

More importantly, I have a few programs I wish to install that require QT5. How can I make sure they find the correct libraries, `/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/lib`?